# Подключение к удаленному серверу по SSH через Powershell с автоматическим заполнением пароля

Tags: python, ssh, powershell

Хочу написать простой скрипт для подключения к серверу по ssh посредством Powershell.

Сейчас приходится прописывать вручную имя_пользователя@ip_сервера -p порт, после чего терминал Powershell предлагает мне ввести пароль. Пароль я знаю, он никогда не меняется.

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы пароль, прописанный в коде скрипта, автоматически подставлялся в тот момент, когда терминал его запрашивает?

Хотелось бы реализовать этот простой момент без генерации ключей или ввода данных о подключении куда либо еще. Если это невозможно сделать методами самого Powershell может быть можно как-то настроить автоматический ввод при помощи библиотеки keyboard из python?

Comment: paramiko вам в помощь

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password